# Overwrite the design in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<ul></ul>` that will be appended by a default `<li></li>` but once the date is picked on the daterangepicker it should be overwritten. It just added the new `<li></li>`

[image: default <ul></ul>]

after i picked a date in the daterangepicker:

[image: after]

Here is my javascript code:

```
    // // Data Picker Initialization
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'center',
        showDropdowns: true,
        startDate: "2020/04/16",
        endDate: "2020/04/16",
        locale: {
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        }
    }, function (start, end, label) {
        var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        window.alert("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        var staticUrlDowntime = "/topdowntime/" + startDate + "/" + endDate;
        console.log(staticUrlDowntime);
        $(document).ready(() => {
            $.ajax({
                url: (staticUrlDowntime),
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: (data) => {
                    $.each(data, (key, val) => {
                        $("#top5Downtime").append("<li>" + val.event_description + " - " + val.error_count + "</li>");
                    });
                }
            })
        });

    })
    //var dta = moment().subtract(1, 'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD"); //code to get the yesterdate
    var dta = "2020-04-16"
    console.log(dta);

    var staticUrlTop5Downtime = "/topdowntime/" + dta;
    console.log(staticUrlTop5Downtime);
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: (staticUrlTop5Downtime),
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: (data) => {
                $.each(data, (key, val) => {
                    $("#top5Downtime").append("<li>" + val.event_description + " - " + val.error_count + "</li>");
                });
            }
        })
    });
    /** CODE FOR BAR CHART */
    const svgContainer = d3.select('#bar-chart')
        .append("svg");

    const margin = 80;
    const svgWidth = 50;
    const width = 1100 - 2 * margin;
    const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

    const chart = svgContainer.append('g')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + svgWidth + "," + margin + ")");

    const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain(sample.map((s) => s.language))
        .padding(0.4)

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 100]);

    // vertical grid lines
    // const makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom()
    //   .scale(xScale)

    const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScale)

    chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    chart.append('g')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    chart.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grid')
        .call(makeYLines()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat('')
        )

    const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
        .data(sample)
        .enter()
        .append('g')

    barGroups
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.language))
        .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
        .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())

    barGroups
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'value')
        .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)

    svgContainer
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
        .attr('y', svgWidth / 3.5)
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text('Percentage (%)')

    svgContainer.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
        .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text('Languages')

    svgContainer.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'title')
        .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
        .attr('y', 40)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text('Top availability CAMs for date: ' + dta);

    $('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        console.log(startDate);
        console.log(endDate);
        // var sampUrl = "/sampleURL/" + startDate;
        // console.log(sampUrl);

        // const svgContainer = d3.select('#bar-chart')
        //     .append("svg");

        // const margin = 80;
        // const svgWidth = 50;
        // const width = 1100 - 2 * margin;
        // const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

        // const chart = svgContainer.append('g')
        //     .attr('transform', "translate(" + svgWidth + "," + margin + ")");

        // const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        //     .range([0, width])
        //     .domain(sample.map((s) => s.language))
        //     .padding(0.4)

        // const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        //     .range([height, 0])
        //     .domain([0, 100]);

        // const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
        //     .scale(yScale)

        // chart.append('g')
        //     .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        //     .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

        // chart.append('g')
        //     .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        // chart.append('g')
        //     .attr('class', 'grid')
        //     .call(makeYLines()
        //         .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        //         .tickFormat('')
        //     )

        // const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
        //     .data(sample)
        //     .enter()
        //     .append('g')

        // barGroups
        //     .append('rect')
        //     .attr('class', 'bar')
        //     .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.language))
        //     .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
        //     .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
        //     .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())

        // barGroups
        //     .append('text')
        //     .attr('class', 'value')
        //     .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
        //     .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
        //     .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        //     .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)

        // svgContainer
        //     .append('text')
        //     .attr('class', 'label')
        //     .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
        //     .attr('y', svgWidth / 3.5)
        //     .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        //     .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        //     .text('Love meter (%)')

        // svgContainer.append('text')
        //     .attr('class', 'label')
        //     .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
        //     .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
        //     .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        //     .text('Languages')

        // svgContainer.append('text')
        //     .attr('class', 'title')
        //     .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
        //     .attr('y', 40)
        //     .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        //     .text('Top availability CAMs for date: ' + startDate);

    });
});
```

Sorry for the messy code. Will clean it up after I'm done experimenting. Also, i have the same problem with the chart it just adds the chart in the bottom and won't overwrite the old chart in the default.
Still kinda new in javascript and learning. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's what `.append` does, use `.html` instead, if you want to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about, if I am not assuming it wrong, empty the container, and then add `li` tags

like

```
success: (data) => {
    $("#top5Downtime").html('');
    $.each(data, (key, val) => {
        $("#top5Downtime").append("<li>" + val.event_description + " - " + val.error_count + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand, what do mean by `only returns one data`?

Comment: It worked! Hahahaha it was the same error on my file that it won't refresh after a change even after hard reloading it.